# navigation window in maximizes screen

Tags: wpf, navigation

i have to Give navigation in my application so i took one navigation window and other as page object.i provided windowstate="maximized" still it dont open in full screen.can anyone help me?

NavigationWindow

```
<NavigationWindow x:Class="SALIENT.View.Start"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Start" Source="../View/MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized">
```

Page

```
<Page x:Class="SALIENT.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Salient" >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a full screen you need to set your "WindowStyle" property to none, try this:

```
<NavigationWindow x:Class="SALIENT.View.Start"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Start" Source="../View/MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None>
```